# Parent table dropped when I removed index reference from a child table in MySQL phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I was working on live db in phpmyadmin, and when I removed an index of a foreign key, it automatically removed the parent tables with data in it. The data was so important for me.
How can I get my table and data back?

I've tried to recreate table but it shows Error:150.

Comment: Only restoring from the backup may help.

Comment: The backup is 3 days old. I've set weekly backups. many records are updated in these 3 days. :(

Comment: Check if the tablespace file is present on the disk. If it is present then save it to somewhere, create empty table with precisely the same structure, drop its newly created tablespace, replace file with a copy of saved one, and import the tablespace. If the file is deleted.. I'm very sorry for you. The probability for to recover deleted file correctly is extremely low (but you may try, of course).